# glyphicon-lock is not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web application, and I'm using Bootstrap 3.

I have the following markup inside my login view to show username and password:

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user blue"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" value="@Model.UserName">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div><br>

  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock blue"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>

  <p class="center col-md-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

However, the `glyphicon-lock` inside the password field is not showing on IE, FF, or Safari:

[image: Screenshot of IE and FF]

Comment: its working on all browsers http://www.bootply.com/XFog6gHafB

Comment: How are you serving your glyphicon assets?

Comment: @KyleMit your edit is wrong it is not showing on Firefox,, can you please undo ur edit .... it should show a regular lock icon

Comment: @nolawipetros it is working but why it does not work on my application i tried other icons such as glyphicon glyphicon-minus all are showing well

Comment: @KyleMit i am referecning the realted css and script inside my _layout view

Comment: @johnG, gotcha!  I was just just trying to simplify the information and make it more uniform.

Comment: what does the url for the glyph look like? can you link directly to the icons...

Comment: did you find why ? I've the same problem